# knockout push data from ajax to observableArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to push data from ajax to knockout observableArray , but it give me an error:

> The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an
>   array, or null, or undefined.

```js
efine(['uiComponent', 'ko', 'jquery'], function (Component, ko, jquery) {

    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            /* State and cities */

            this.selectCity();
        },

        selectCity: function () {
var myViewModel = {}; 
            state = ko.observableArray([]);

            jquery.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/hamechio/region.php',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    myViewModel = data;
                    state.push(data);
                }
            });

            console.log(state); 
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line should be change as per my knowledge.

```
 state = ko.observableArray([]);
```

to this

```
var state = ko.observableArray();
```

Comment: the key piece of the answer is "var" the suggestion is that it's a variable scope issue. passing an empty array into observableArray doesn't hurt but is also not needed.

Comment: I removed my downvote and comment after Negi added the `var` declaration. The initial answer didn't mention it. I still feel the answer would be better if it A) didn't change the way the array is initialized (since it doesn't matter), and B) actually explains why the change fixes anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ajax scope ques.

you can use 'var'.

like this:

```
var state = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest looking through the Documentation that has lots of working examples: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Firstly, your View Model is the object on which all of your programme is built on.  This object contains all of the data to show (as knockout observable property "methods") and commands to receive (functions).  Therefore you need to define the view model to contain everything your application needs to do:

```
var viewModel = {
    //Bindings
    state = ko.observableArray();
}
```

Now you can write to the `viewModel.state()`:

if data is an array and you don't want to track changes to data's items:

```
viewModel.state(data);
```

or push them one at a time:

```
data.foreach(function(el){ viewModel.state.push(el); });
```

If you want to track changes to each individual item's properties, you will need to use the second method and convert each element into an object composed of `ko.observable`s.